# Turning 4 GB SD card into 2 GB SD (for AKAI MPC 2000xl)

Tags: usb-flash-drive, disk-space, sd-card

I got a device (AKAI MPC 2000xl) that allows me to use **2GB SD cards only**.

How can I format a **4 GB** card to make device think that it is 2 GB?

Notes:

- It is absolutely okay if I lose 2 GB of space.
- I can use Windows as well as Linux - so any operating systems solutions are appreciated

Comment: You could partition the device into two partitions of 2 GB each. But I don't know how the device will cope with that (some devices will only see the first partition; others might reject the card).

Comment: @Renan, actualy thinking about this way :)

Comment: It may even be a hardware-level restriction. A 2GB SD card [is around $4](http://www.amazon.com/mn/search/?_encoding=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&field-keywords=2gb%20sd%20card&linkCode=ur2&tag=nathhink-20&url=search-alias%3Daps&x=0&y=0)... it might be easier to just buy a new one in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not a matter of size. A 4GB Secure Digital card speaks **SDHC**, which is different enough from the original SD protocol that SDHC cards cannot be used with a device that only supports SD.